# Discount with PayPal REST API

Tags: paypal

When submitting a payment via PayPal's REST API a collection of Items must be provided where the price * quantity = total.

The following screen grab from Fiddler illustrates my problem:

[image]

The value for the "price" element must be in the format "0.00". However, in the case above I started with a price for loose photos of "£0.08" then added 20% VAT to give "£0.096". 300 * £0.096 is £28.80, so the total cost of the order is given correctly. Problem is, I have no way to present the unit cost to PayPal. Could anyone please advise how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar issues with shipping options and chose to write my own shopping cart code which displays individual items selected plus tax and shipping options. A 'pay using PayPal' button on the form simply submits the total price to PayPal. This gives me total flexibility - I recently switched to free shipping on orders over $x. Also the shopping cart is much faster and responsive than using Paypal for every item selected - so I get more orders going through to completion - always a good thing!

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I think I need to go the same way and create a shopping basket and provide only a total to PayPal.